# How to go through the controls of a ribbon in devexpress winform

Tags: c#, devexpress

Hi everybody I'm trying to get all the names of the ribbon pages' ribbon form, the ribbon pages groups and bar buttom items and show them in a gridcontrol's XtraForm childForm. In my case I did it:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("PAGE");
dt.Columns.Add("GROUP");
dt.Columns.Add("OPTION");
DataRow dr;
XtraForm frm = (XtraForm)Application.OpenForms["FrmPrincipal"];
RibbonControl parentRibbon = (RibbonControl)frm.Controls["ribbon"];
//parentRibbon.Pages.GetPageByText
foreach (RibbonPageGroup group in parentRibbon.SelectedPage.Groups)
{
    foreach (BarItemLink link in group.ItemLinks)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["PAGE"] = parentRibbon.SelectedPage.Text;
        dr["GROUP"] = group.Text;
        dr["OPTION"] = link.Caption;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
gcData.DataSource = dt;
```

[image]
The problem is that I got the names of the ribbon page focused. How can I get all even the other ribbon pages?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are looping through all groups of `SelectedPage` so you do not even access other pages if the `RibbonControl`

if you nest your loop inside another loop where you loop through all pages of `parentRibbon.Pages` then you will be able to find all groups in all pages

Comment: Thanks in advance I added foreach (RibbonPage page in parentRibbon.Pages) and I got it